# Localization of Modules over Dedekind domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, algebraic-number-theory, principal-ideal-domains, dedekind-domain

I have been reading the book *Algebraic Number Theory* by *J.W.S. Cassels & A. Frohlich* and I am currently stuck in a proof about Localization of Modules over Dedekind domains.

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, $p$ one of its prime ideal, and $U=frac(R)$ its quotient field.  Let $V$ be a vector space over $U$ and $M$ a $R_p$-submodule such that $M$ spans $V$ (it means $M$ contains a basis for $V$).

Then I know that I can use modules over PID to decompose $M=\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^nR_pv_i\right)\oplus \left(\bigoplus_{\text{some }k}R_p/(p^k)\right)$.  Then because of dimension counting, we conclude that the torsion term should not exist or else the dimension of the module will be greated than that of $V$, which should not exist in modules over PID.

Is my proof correct or not?  I have seen a similar question [(link)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146175/example-of-a-non-free-module-of-a-dedekind-domain-r-that-can-be-embedded-in-a-fi) asked before for examples of submodules not free in Dedekind domains.  So I guess it means that if the underlying ring $R_p$ is a PID, then all submodules of finite-dimension vector spaces should be free?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Is your question how do you prove there is no torsion?  I think it's a little easier than what you described.  If pm = 0 in M, then pm = 0 in V, but then (1/p) (pm) = 0 in V, so m = 0.

Comment: @CJD thanks and so the reason for general Dedekind domain $R$ we cannot conclude this result, is because we don't have the general structure theory of modules over $R$?

Comment: Thanks! Which result do you mean?  I feel like what you wrote up above was for a general Dedekind domain R

Comment: @CJD I meant if $R$ is a Dedekind domain, $V$ a $frac(R)$-module and $M$ a $R$ submodule of $V$, then even if we can still say that $Tor(M)=0$, we cannot conclude that $M$ is free since $M=\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^k Rm_i\right) \oplus Tor(M)$ only works for modules over PID?

Comment: I agree with what you wrote that we cannot conclude M is free in general, and I think the link you gave up above gives a counter-example.